# For-loop within a function does not return index variable when the function is invoked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code a function that, when it is invoked, will return the value of the index variable from a for-loop within the function.

This is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
    for(var i = 0; i++) {
        return i;
    }

    alert(i);
}

myFunction();
```

If I ditch the function, the for-loop works fine, if I replace the "return" with a JavaScript-"alert". What I am trying to achieve is that the result of the for-loop is only alerted when the function is invoked.

Comment: `return` ends the function. what do you like to achieve with a `for` loop?

Comment: As @NinaScholz says, because your `alert` is after the `return`, it will never be fired.

Comment: Sounds like your function should just make a list/array and return that.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is invalid, it's missing the stopping condition. You need to specify another block in the `for` loop otherwise it will throw an error.

```
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++)
```

And if your loop is correct, with the `return` statement will quit the `function` and by consequence the `for` loop as well will be ended. So all code after `return` statement will be ignored including your `alert(i)` statement.

In other words all the code after `return` will be ommitted and ignored, because the function call has ended due to `return` keyword.

## Edit:

If you are trying to make an array or list of numbers and return it when you invoke th function, that's what you should do:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        array.push(i);
    }
    return array;
}

alert(myFunction());
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Could you give me a code example?

Comment: @MaxSvenman Your alert will only happen after the for loop is completed. Which part of your code was supposed to make the for loop stop running? The way you wrote it (if we get rid of the return statement) it would be an infinite loop and your alert will never happen.

Comment: @MaxSvenman In other words all the code after `return` will be ommitted and ignored, because the function call has ended due to `return` keyword.

Comment: Ok, I see. Should I use "break"? Should I do "return i;" and then "break", followed by "alert(i)" within the funciton?

Comment: @MaxSvenman, No. Anything after `return` will not be executed. What you should do is `alert(myFunction())`

Comment: No, your function should only return 1 time once it is fully completed. If you want your function to return a list of numbers, then your function should build that list of numbers and return it once it is complete.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that the for-loop only loops when the function is invoked, and that the result of the for-loop is alerted only when the function is invoked. I know how to create a for-loop outside of a function that can do the job, but for a bigger project I have to "control" the for-loop only to run when a function is invoked.

Comment: YES! A list of all of those numbers. Do I have to have an empty array or something to achieve that?

Comment: "_the result of the for-loop is alerted_" So you need to generate all the numbers, exit the for loop, then alert. Sounds like you don't need a return at all since nothing is going to actually use the numbers you generated. Yes, I would just make an empty array, then inside your loop add numbers to that array, then once the loop is done alert the array contents.

Comment: @MaxSvenman Take a look at my Edit, you will find what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

[**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) runs a function on each element of an array and always returns an array of each of the functions' results. There are 2 demos both are the same pretty much in principle.

**Details are commented in demo**

### Demo 1

```js
/* Collect all divs into a NodeList with
|| querySelectorAll()
|| Then convert the NodeList into an array with
|| Array.from()
*/
var divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div'));

/* Run the array method map() on divs[]
|| map() will run a function on each element of
|| an array. It will return a new array that
|| comprises of each of the functions' return.
*/
var INDEX_VALUE = divs.map(function(div, idx, divs) {

      // Get the text of each div
      var txt = div.textContent;

      // Display INDEX VALUE and text in console
      console.log('Index: ' + idx + ' Content: '+txt);

        // Return an array of all the results
        return idx;
      });

    console.log(INDEX_VALUE);
```

```html
<div>01</div>
<div>ponies</div>
<div>unicorns</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>world</div>
```

### Demo 2

```js
var arr = ['01', 'ponies', 'unicorns', 'foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'world'];

var INDEX_VALUE = arr.map(function(ele, idx, arr) {
  var size = ele.length;
  console.log('Index: ' + idx + ' String: ' + ele + ' Chars: ' + size);
  return idx;

});
```

Comment: "_I am trying to code a function that, when it is invoked, will return the value of the index variable from a for-loop within the function_" I'm not sure how the code in your answer gets anywhere near that description.

Comment: A function is invoked on each iteration of `map()` and will return a value. The `alarm()` is useless and annoying, the console is far better way to see results.

Comment: @csmckelvey I updated the answer and emphasized the `INDEX_VALUE` that is returned, I hope it's plain to see now.

Comment: It is still not clear why you introduced a bunch of HTML and additional functions (`Array.from()`, `document.querySelectorAll()`, `map()`) to a question about a simple javascript loop.

Comment: Why not? It's not like OP had much details on objective. I'll make a plain demo so it's less confusing.

Comment: I think they gave exact details on objective - "_I am trying to code a function that, when it is invoked, will return the value of the index variable from a for-loop within the function_"

Comment: I believe Mr. Svenman is a singular entity not *they*. I guess a for loop is enough details for you. Look at my profile and  the answers and the majority of them have a functional answer with details. If there's not enough info on the question I'll add enough to make it work as a [mcve]. I'm sorry that you don't understand my answer. I thought it was obvious that map() does everything that the OP requires.

Comment: You don't know whether Max Svenman identifies as a male, female or something else. Singular they is appropriate in this context.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I have a good idea that Max Svenman identifies as a male as he is represented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8567926/max-svenman)

Comment: "Singular they is appropriate in this context"* No it isn't and *"singular they"* is an oxymoron. I know this is one of your accounts @csmckelvey

Comment: This is a profile picture, nothing more. More info here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/singular-nonbinary-they and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they.

Comment: @csmckelvey I prefer to observe what data is provided and use [common sense](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/common%20sense) rather than be grammatically awkward. That's what people do in real life when conversing.

Comment: I don't know why you think I'm Tom.